# How to use multiple variables of results in one Http Request in other Http Request

Tags: jmeter

I just started my career as a Junior Tester

Step1: Requested XML Data using HTTP Request

```
    Path: /vitalhub/rest/patientlists
    ResponseData:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <patientLists lastRefresh="2015-11-16T15:48:21.050-05:00" count="4">
   <patientList modifiable="false" uid="0000000000204016">
    <vhSysSrc>cerner</vhSysSrc>
    <name>Test List</name>
   </patientList>
   <patientList modifiable="false" uid="0000000000204019">
    <vhSysSrc>cerner</vhSysSrc>
    <name>123</name>
   </patientList>
   <patientList modifiable="false" uid="0000000000204021">
    <vhSysSrc>cerner</vhSysSrc>
    <name>Random Patient List</name>
   </patientList>
   <patientList modifiable="false" uid="0000000000204023">
    <vhSysSrc>cerner</vhSysSrc>
    <name>Custom List</name>
   </patientList>
   </patientLists>
```

Step2: Added a XpathExtractor as

```
   Reference Name: listName
   Xpath Query:patientLists/patientList/name/text()
```

Step3: Added debugSampler and these were the results

```
   JMeterVariables:
   JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
   JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@393d25f8
   START.HMS=134134
   START.MS=1447267294003
   START.YMD=20151111
   TESTSTART.MS=1447709583847
   applicationDomain=VitalHubChart
   bulkCiphers=NONE
   deviceId= dev1
   devicePassword=vitalhub123
   key=55fbcb5c-f71a-42ce-995e-72a7c44145b3
   key_1=55fbcb5c-f71a-42ce-995e-72a7c44145b3
   key_matchNr=1
   listName=Test List
   listName_1=Test List
   listName_2=123
   listName_3=Random Patient List
   listName_4=Custom List
   listName_matchNr=4
   password=testcp
   sessionId=f3e8a037-d6e6-4ed4-b5db-993c713417f0
   sessionId_1=f3e8a037-d6e6-4ed4-b5db-993c713417f0
   sessionId_matchNr=1
   user=testcp
   userName=testcp
   userPass= testcp
```

Step4: Added an other Http Request to get the results by using ListName

```
  Path: /vitalhub/rest/patientLists/name/${listName_1}
```

By using Step4 I can just get info of a single list. I have to change it to `listName_2..4`  to get different list results

How can I  automate these requests?

I tried using `foreach` loop and `RegularExpressionExtractor` and tried using `BeanShellPostProcessor`, but was unable to solve it

I would be thankful if anyone can answer my question.

Comment: I did the same thing but not able to run the ForEachLoop and for extracted list, not able to get output.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is using [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configured as:

- Input Variable Prefix: `listName`
- Output Variable Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `currentList`
- Add "_" before number?: `checked`

  [image: ForEach Controller]

This way you will be able to iterate all the `listName_X` variables:

[image: ForEach Controller in action]

See [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) guide for another example which extracts all HTML links from web page and hits them all using ForEach Controller.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't add HTTP Request in ForEach loop. I will try as you explained